# iOS class selection NSDictionary or Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I am learning iOS programming and wouldn't mind an opinion or two on the most appropriate class to use for my application, `NSDictionary` or `Core Data`. I would like to be able to create an array of records with a set of attributes.

For example, Name: Joe Citizen, Age:38, Sex: Male, Profession: Zookeeper, City: Sydney etc.

I would like to be able to randomly select a record with one or more attribute. Last night I was moving towards a `NSDictionary` solution, where I would embed the properties into a bit mapped word, convert it to a string, and then append strings to that string to make a key unique such as `k_stringbitpattern_uniquenumber`. To get the random identifier I would generate a random number, mask it, convert it to a string etc, to the point that  I realized that it is getting too cumbersome.

I am new to iOS programming and am trying to consider speed, memory usage, elegance and reuse. Getting 
seasoned opinions will help.

I apologize in advance if my use of terms is not strictly correct (i.e. array of records).
Oh yes, the records are read-only, and I hope to be able to extend my app later to pull data from a website. Any helpful
comments appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you want to select randomly and you don't say how big your data set is but you should most probably use core data.

Comment: I agree with @Wain.  Also Core Data is a framework, not a single class.  You also need to consider how you are initially storing your data.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I thought I added that I expect the data set to be from a couple hundred words to perhaps a couple thousand. I guess that will affect the method of storage. The random record select is a feature (not bug :) ) of my app design. Thanks for your opinion. So far, based on seasoned opinion, it seems that I should be looking towards the core data framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a question for [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

My answer for this is build the simplest and easiest to understand model possible and don't worry about optimizations.

In your case, I would recommend an `NSArray` of plain old Objective-C objects. In your object class, make all the attributes into properties. Use `NSNumber` instead of `NSInteger` or `int` for numbers. Searches can be done with a simple for loop or `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

Later on, if based on performance needs, switching to Core Data should not be too painful. Look into [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). It is a much needed simplification of the complexities of Core Data.

I would not recommend building your own indexes with NSDictionary. At that point, you are beginning to write your own database. Other people have solved that problem.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery. Much appreciated answer. I look into these suggestions as well.